# How can I send ping method in Binance websocket?

Tags: python, websocket, binance

I want to take data from Binance by websocket. In a few minutes connection will be closed. How can I run ping/pong method in Binance websocket?

```
import json
import websocket

def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print("Error Binance", error)

def on_close(ws):
    print("### closed ###")

def on_open(ws):
    pass

def on_ping(ws, message):
    pass

def on_pong(ws, message):
    # ws.send(json.dumps({"method": "ping"}))
    # ws.send({"method": "ping"})
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://fstream.binance.com/stream?streams=btcusdt@depth",
                                on_message=on_message, on_error=on_error, on_close=on_close, on_ping=on_ping,
                                on_pong=on_pong, on_open=on_open)
    ws.run_forever(ping_interval=10, ping_timeout=5)
```

Comment: I suggest you to use this other lib to work with websockets in python : https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: How can I send ping methon in this lib for Binance?

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, I would suggest you to use [websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable) package, which allows to use the async paradigm instead of callbacks.

In your case, you want to use it as a client. Here is an example of a client that sends and receives a single message:

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def hello():
    async with websockets.connect("ws://localhost:8765") as websocket:
        await websocket.send("Hello world!")
        await websocket.recv()

asyncio.run(hello())
```

You can adapt it to your use case.

Comment: Thanks. I know this method, but how can I send ping for Binance? I can't adapt, because I don't know what I have to insert in 'send' brackets

Comment: It depends on what the Binance websocket server establishes. Are you supposed to send something in order to start receiving ? Or just connect and start receiving is enough ?